# How to Convert Image to Base64 in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, base64

I'm trying to convert image to base64 but the result can't view as image.

Here my code below.

```
File image = File(path);
final bytes = image.readAsBytesSync();
print(base64Encode(bytes));
```

Result :

```
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
```

But the result above can't view as image.
I used these website to check
[codebeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

[base64decode](https://www.base64decode.net/base64-image-decoder)

Is there any solutions for this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Print` function will not print everything 
If you need to copy this long string, you can set break point and view in `Variables` 
You can see image below

[image]

Comment: The `print` function *should* print everything. Since Base64 encoded strings are pure ASCII, there should be no problem printing all of the string.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer, the result isn't different from what OP is getting.

Answer (score 4):

How do you try to *view* the image?

A base-64 string is not a valid image format.

You can use [`Uri.dataFromBytes(bytes, mimeType: "image/jpg")`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Uri/Uri.dataFromBytes.html) to create a `data:` URI containing the image.
That URI's payload will be base-64 encoded for you.
If you use that URI as the `src` of your `img` element in a browser, it should be displayed as the image.